# Cant get ImageView onItemClick from custom ListView Android [EDIT]

Tags: android, android-listview, null, android-imageview

I've implemented a custom ListView, this is the structure of each row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imagenEvento"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"     
android:contentDescription="@string/contenidoImagen"       
/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sitio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fecha"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've setted to my ListView and adapter and it works fine while accesing data, but when i try to convert an ImageView to a byteArray so i can send it to another Activitie, i can't get the ImageView

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);       
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            //creo el nuevo objeto para poder llamarlo
            Intent intent = new Intent(AllProductsActivity.this, PostActivity.class);

            //Creo la informacion para pasar entre actividades
            Bundle informacion= new Bundle();
            informacion.putInt("id", eventos.get(position).getID());

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.id.imagenEvento);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            informacion.putByteArray("imagen", byteArray);                              
        }

    });
```

I'm getting my bmp NULL:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.id.imagenEvento);
```

I guess i should indicate the position of the item due it's in a ListView but i don't know how to do it

[EDIT]
The problem is solved, i'm getting the image in the next Activity, but, i'm getting always the top image from the ListView of this Activity, how can i get the clicked Image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImageView` that your using is just a reference so no need to convert it into an array just pass the reference directly as `static` Or make a `static class` that holds such references so that you can use it later, But also you can save the image of the `imageview` as bitmap and encode save that image as byte array and decode it when needed, and later use it imageView as `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

```
imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();


public String BitmapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return image;
}


public Bitmap StringToBitmap(String image){
    byte[] encodeByte =  Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0 , encodeByte.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Coding the bmp to String and decoding it, i got the URL of my Image

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(a.getResources(), R.id.imagenEvento);
```

to get your bitmap image. Try this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewByID(R.id.iamgeenEvento);
Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Your original code was trying to decode the imageview itself as a bitmap and as it's not a bitmap would return a null value.

Comment: 07-24 10:11:22.851: E/AndroidRuntime(651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 10:11:22.851: E/AndroidRuntime(651): java.lang.ClassCastException: eventos.MyClassAdapter$DownloadedDrawable

Comment: if it is not a BitmapDrawable, what kind of drawable do you put there, and how do you expect to get a Bitmap from it ?